# How to get acute sign when writing an R markdown document?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm trying to write a document with Rmarkdown. Kniting the Pdf works, but I don't get the acute sign.

I already tried :

```
\'{e}'\'{e}'n
```

within a word, like I did with Latex earlier, but the pdf document shows

```
’{e}’{e}n
```

in the the document, does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use `$ ... $` around your `\'{e}`.

```
$\'{e}\'{e}$n
```

results in:

> één

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: would you know a specific cheat sheet for this which has codings for all special characters?

Comment: You mean something like this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes?